# Django adding to duplicate model object with Many-to-Many Relation to same model ('self') result with add to original object

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, addition

I have a duplicate method of an object that contains a Many-to-Many Relation to same 'self', to duplicate I used the 'copy' method.

**Problem**: I noticed that when later adding to this field new (self) objects, they were added also to the original object many-to-many field.

```
class CanvasOperation(models.Model):
    dependencies = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="+", blank=True)

    def duplicate(self):
        duplicated = copy.copy(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add symmetrical=False to the field definition.

```
dependencies = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="+", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/